# pyspark-strange behavior of count function inside agg

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am using spark 2.4.0
I am observing a strange behavior while using count function to aggregate.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
tst=sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2),(1,5),(2,None),(2,3),(3,None),(3,None)],schema=['col1','col2'])
tst.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   2|
|   1|   5|
|   2|null|
|   2|   3|
|   3|null|
|   3|null|
+----+----+

tst.groupby('col1').agg(F.count('col2')).show()
+----+-----------+
|col1|count(col2)|
+----+-----------+
|   1|          2|
|   3|          0|
|   2|          1|
+----+-----------+
```

Here you can see that the null values are not counted. I searched for the docus, but no where it is mentioned that the function count does not count null values.
More surprising for me is this

```
tst.groupby('col1').agg(F.count(F.col('col2').isNull())).show()
+----+---------------------+
|col1|count((col2 IS NULL))|
+----+---------------------+
|   1|                    2|
|   3|                    2|
|   2|                    2|
+----+---------------------+
```

Here I am totally confused. When I use isNull(), shouldn't it count only null values? Why is it counting all the values?

Any thing i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases the results that you see are the expected ones.

Concerning the first example: Checking the Scala [source of count](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/77006b2c65e0e4b6b9facddbb13aa88a264adbe2/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/Count.scala#L51) there is a subtle difference between `count(*)` and `count('col2')`:

> *FUNC*(*) - Returns the total number of retrieved rows, including rows containing null.
> *FUNC*(expr[, expr...]) - Returns the number of rows for which the supplied expression(s) are all non-null.

This explains why the `null` entries are not counted.

If you change the code to

```python
tst.groupby('col1').agg(F.count('*')).show()
```

you get

```
+----+--------+
|col1|count(1)|
+----+--------+
|   1|       2|
|   3|       2|
|   2|       2|
+----+--------+
```

---

About the second part: the expression `F.col('col2').isNull()` returns a boolean value. No matter what the actual value of this boolean is, the row is counted and therefore you see a `2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That explains a lot. The second part , i must have used in a filter and then counted.