# Count(*) equivalent for Spark SQL in Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to count the number of rows after aggregating some dataset with more than 1 column,
for example

```
val iWantToCount = someDataSet
      .groupBy($"x", $"y")
      .agg(count().as("Num_of_rows"))
```

but there is not overload for `count` which takes no arguments.

any other options I have?

**edit:**

does `count("*")` is the right way to go?

Comment: How about `count("1")` ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I read on another thread that if I'll use ``count(lit(1))`` for example it'll be like writing ``count($"x")`` which is not what I want

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but maybe helpful:  [behavior of count function inside agg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62575807/2129801)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq((1, "qwe", 1200),
    (1, "qwe", 1234),
    (1, "rte", 4673),
    (2, "ewr", 4245), (2, "ewr", 8973)
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

println(df.groupBy("col1", "col2").count().count())
```

Comment: I want to use the result of the count as a column in the result of the aggregation, so the resulting schema will look like
col1 | col2 | num_of_rows

Answer (score 1):

Try this script (the below import is required for using `lit`):

```
import.spark.implicits._

//dummy data    
val df = Seq((1, "qwe", 1200),
    (1, "qwe", 1234),
    (1, "rte", 4673),
    (2, "ewr", 4245), (2, "ewr", 8973)
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

df.groupBy("col1","col2").agg(count(lit(1)).alias("num_of_rows")).show
```

The data is grouped based on 1st two columns and deriving the count in new column.

Comment: Hi Rocky welcome to stack overflow. Code only answers can sometimes attract down votes, To avoid this I suggest you add a few words like "given a data-frame like this we can perform an aggregation as show below" sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `count("*")` inside `agg()`. It is the same as `count(lit(1))`

Source (see `// Turn count(*) into count(1)` comment in the source code bellow:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.2.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala

```
/**
   * Aggregate function: returns the number of items in a group.
   *
   * @group agg_funcs
   * @since 1.3.0
   */
  def count(e: Column): Column = withAggregateFunction {
    e.expr match {
      // Turn count(*) into count(1)
      case s: Star => Count(Literal(1))
      case _ => Count(e.expr)
    }
  }
```